# Finding all the Wikipedia article IDs belonging to people only

Tags: sparql, wikipedia

I have the bz2 data dump (specifically from enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 downloaded from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/) and each article ID (or page ID?) but I would like to obtain a list of only those article(/page) IDs that belong to people (or any other ontology category I'd like). **Edit:** I have used [WikiExtractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor) to get the articles in JSON format and the IDs do live as a key, e.g.

```
   {
    "id": "316",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=316", 
    "text": "Academy Award for Best Production Design\.... 
    }
```

**Edit:** They may not be "article IDs" but page IDs (apologies for my confusion).

I know I can use SPARQL to get the list of people, but I just need the article IDs entered [here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/) -- though the output is also limited to 500 I believe.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{ ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .}
```

I just need the article IDs using the same query basically, but all IDs and not a subset.

Comment: I'm confused. What is a Wikipedia "article ID"? Are you really talking about Wikipedia? Or DBpedia? I'm asking because in Wikipedia the URIs start with `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/` while in DBpedia resources use `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` . It is also unclear which bz2 data dump you have

Comment: regarding the limit of 500, at http://dbpedia.org/sparql you would have a limit of 1000. And this can be solved by using `order by ?p limit 1000 offset (n * 1000)` n times until no result is returned back

Comment: Clearly, I'd just use a pipeline if Linux commandline tools like awk to get just the lines with `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person`

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I've amended the question with additional information. I believe I am after a filter on the page ID, i.e. the one use in the URL.

Comment: Not sure if such an ID is in DBpedia, all you can get and might be relevant is: `SELECT * WHERE
{ 
?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> ; dbo:wikiPageID ?dbpedia_page_id; <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#wasDerivedFrom> ?derived_from_url; foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipedia_url} limit 100`

Comment: This looks great -- thanks. Though, is there a more efficient way of getting this list rather than porting N times to CSV? Lastly, I tried to fold in ?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor.
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/occupation> ?occupation. into that query with birthday and death if available but couldn't get the syntax right. Apologies if outside of confines of question.

Comment: If you extended my query - I used some short form which allows for writing the subject `?p` just once. so it should be `; dbo:knownFor ?knownFor; dbo:occupation ?occupation .`

Comment: and no, there is no way to get all results at once - at least not with the public SPARQL endpoint. The limit is there because it's a shared service used by many people. Indeed, you could easily load the dataset into your own triple store -

Comment: OK understood, though it appears to only return if the entry exists, how do I include those that don't exist for `?deathDate` and `?birthDate`. I also noticed that some returned values are `"1989-4-12"` and `"1989-4-12"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>` thus duplicating certain rows...

Comment: Yes, it only returns the entities that have all values with the query above. If you want optional data, just do `OPTIONAL {?p dbo:birthDate ?birthDate}` for example.

Comment: and yes, the data isn't perfect ... the data is extracted automatically from Wikipedia Infoboxes (and some other sources) - the data in Wikipedia itself can be dirty, and the extraction process is probably also not perfect.